# In Neo4j is the default isolation level always READ_COMMITTED or is it the case only when extending it with Java?

Tags: java, neo4j, transactions, transaction-isolation

I am reading the documentation provided by Neo4j https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/transactions/, but as the link says, the rules provided in that explanation are valid when talking about the java-extension, what about Neo4j without any extension? I am interested in particular in the default isolation level, what is the default one in the basic case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default neo4j isolation level in all cases is `READ_COMMITTED`, which means that a transaction (A) that reads a node/relationship does not block another transaction (B) from writing to that node/relationship before A has completed.